# Destroy previous fragments from layout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a layout which I populate with two fragments. I have written a service that fetches data online and then repopulate the layout with two fragments . I want to destroy old fragments and then place the new one but this keeps on adding the new fragments in the layout. If I use **beginTransaction().replace** that only adds one fragment at a time in layout . How can I achieve this thing?

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {         

                Fragment f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentNowPlaying");
                if (f != null)
                    transaction.remove(f);

                f = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentChannel");
                if (f != null)
                    transaction.remove(f);

                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                FragmentNowPlaying fragmentNowPlaying = new FragmentNowPlaying();
                transaction = fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content,fragmentNowPlaying, "fragmentNowPlaying");
                transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();

                transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                FragmentChannel fragmentchannel = new FragmentChannel();
                transaction = fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content,fragmentchannel, "fragmentChannel");
                transaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Do you really need two fragments that overlap? Or can you have two separate containers in your activity's layout file?

Comment: I can have two separate containers in activity . I was avoiding that thing to not overload my layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two separate `FrameLayout` containers for each `Fragment`. This way you can `replace()` them independently of each other.

Comment: does replacing a fragment completely destroy the previous one ?

Comment: @Shahzeb What do you mean by "destroy"?

Comment: I don't want the previous fragments on pause. I want to replace them from stack